# How to get stamp in shell script in JSON file using jq tool?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, timestamps, json, jq

I have question regarding shell scripting and jq tool to create a json file with timestamps.

```
echo "{\"vtg\":[$value]}" | jq -a '. + {date: now|strflocaltime("%r")}' > sample.json
```

With this command I am getting below json file.

```
{
 "vtg": [
 11.769,
 11.769,
 11.339,
 11.788,
 11.867,
 11.886,
 11.808,
 11.339,
 11.554,
 11.182
 ],
 "date": "03:31:52 PM"
}
```

But I want time stamp like,

```
"date": [
  15,
  31,
  52
]
```

When do

```
 strptime("%H:%M:%SZ")
```

I am supposed to get that time-stamp in the format I want. But it gives me error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:10): strptime/1 requires string inputs and arguments
```

Can someone help me how to get that time stamp in JSON file?

Answer (score 4):

The `strptime()` function is used to *parse* a formatted time (the inverse of what `strftime()` does).  You want `strftime()`.

Using `jq`:

```bsh
jq -n 'now as $t | { date: [ ($t|strftime("%H")), ($t|strftime("%M")), ($t|strftime("%S")) ] }'
```

This uses `strftime()` to format the time given by the `now` function.  Use `strflocaltime()` to convert the time to local time.

If that's too wordy or seems inefficient (we're actually calling `strftime()` once for each element of the `date` array!), then consider creating a `HH:MM:SS` timestamp *string*, and then splitting it on the colons:

```bsh
jq -n '{ date: (now | strftime("%H:%M:%S") | split(":")) }'
```

Either of the above commands may produce

```json
{
  "date": [
    "07",
    "01",
    "23"
  ]
}
```

Complete script (uses `jo` to safely create the initial `vtg` array from the values of a named `bash` array):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

value=(11.769 11.769 11.339 11.788 11.867 11.886 11.808 11.339 11.554 11.182)

jo vtg="$( jo -a "${value[@]}" )" |
jq '. += now as $t | { date: [ ($t|strftime("%H")), ($t|strftime("%M")), ($t|strftime("%S")) ] }'

# or...

jo vtg="$( jo -a "${value[@]}" )" |
jq '. += { date: (now | strftime("%H:%M:%S") | split(":")) }'
```

You could obviously also create the date section of the data on the fly with `jo` reading from the `date` command:

```bsh
jo vtg="$(  jo -a "${value[@]}" )" \
   date="$( jo -a $( date +'%H %M %S' ) )"
```

This relies on the shell splitting the output from `date` on the spaces in the format string.  You will get the local time from the above.

The `jo` tool is available from https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/